# Using io.tmpfile() with shell command, ran via io.popen, in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm using Lua in Scite on Windows, but hopefully this is a general Lua question.

Let's say I want to write a temporary string content to a temporary file in Lua - which I want to be eventually read by another program, - and I tried using `io.tmpfile()`:

```lua
mytmpfile = assert( io.tmpfile() )
mytmpfile:write( MYTMPTEXT )
mytmpfile:seek("set", 0) -- back to start
print("mytmpfile" .. mytmpfile .. "<<<")
mytmpfile:close()
```

I like `io.tmpfile()` because it is noted in https://www.lua.org/pil/21.3.html :

> The tmpfile function returns a handle for a temporary file, open in read/write mode. That file is automatically removed (deleted) when your program ends.

However, when I try to print `mytmpfile`, I get:

```
C:\Users\ME/sciteLuaFunctions.lua:956: attempt to concatenate a FILE* value (global 'mytmpfile')
>Lua: error occurred while processing command
```

I got the explanation for that here [Re: path for io.tmpfile() ?](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-10/msg00827.html):

> > > how do I get the path used to generate the temp file created by io.tmpfile()
> >
> > You can't. The whole point of tmpfile is to give you a file handle without
> > giving you the file name to avoid race conditions.
>
> And indeed, on some OSes, the file has no name.

So, it will not be possible for me to use the filename of the tmpfile in a command line that should be ran by the OS, as in:

```lua
f = io.popen("python myprog.py " .. mytmpfile)
```

So my questions are:

- Would it be somehow possible to specify this tmpfile file handle as the input argument for the externally ran program/script, say in `io.popen` - instead of using the (non-existing) tmpfile filename?
- If above is not possible, what is the next best option (in terms of not having to maintain it, i.e. not having to remember to delete the file) for opening a temporary file in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a temp filename with `os.tmpname`.

```
local n = os.tmpname()
local f = io.open(n, 'w+b')
f:write(....)
f:close()
os.remove(n)
```

If your purpose is sending some data to a python script, you can also use 'w' mode in popen.

```
--lua
local f = io.popen(prog, 'w')
f:write(....)
```

```
#python
import sys
data = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: Many thanks, that looks good as the next best thing ... Although, I would still love to hear, if anyone has any workarounds about `io.tmpfile`

Comment: No workaround in lua, because getting file name from a file handler is OS specific. [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile)